# Black Screen after installing NVIDIA drivers on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, bios, recovery-mode

I have a dual boot system with an NVIDIA RTX 3070. I've had no problems in the past working on ubuntu and using windows for gaming. I tried to install Nvidia Drivers on ubuntu to get my GPU working on the OS.

Ubuntu 22.04
AMD Ryzen 3700X
RTX 3070

I went into settings -> additional drivers, and it used to be "X" something and I switched to NVIDIA 505 or 525 and restarted my PC.

After turning off and on sever times I cannot get any video signal onto my display. I've tried booting into bios, using F2 but nothing works. No matter what I press I cannot get any thing to display whatsoever on my screen, not even my ASUS startup logo.

The computer seems to be OK. The hard drive light is blinking normally and when I turn it on I suspect it to be booting into linux, although I cannot see this, because my wireless headphones tell me it is connected, and I can hear indications when I reach max volume and min volume.

My display gets no HDMI signal from any of the ports on my motherboard or my graphics card.

I have no idea what to do. I suspect I'm trying to access GRUB & BIOS incorrectly so if I could get some help taking this from the top that'd be much appreciated.

Comment: I tried holding shift on my keyboard after turning on my computer but I got nothing. MY monitor doesn't turn on with my computer as it should, and when I turn it on manually it just tells me there is no signal. Would it matter which HDMI port I plug the monitor into?

Comment: I turned on my PC, and immediately started spamming F2 on the keyboard. Nothing happened. I know there is a working windows set up on the machine, but now that I cant even boot into BIOS this is getting really scary...